# apply boost::fusion::for_each to boost::fusion::vector with mutable function object

Tags: c++, boost, boost-fusion

I am trying to use boost::fusion::vector. However, I am in trouble with the very simple problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/fusion/container/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/algorithm.hpp>

using namespace std;

struct A{
    template <class T>
    void operator()(const T& t) {
        x++;
        cout << t << endl;
    }

    int x = 0;
};

int main(){
    A a;
    boost::fusion::vector<int, int, int> tuple{3,4,5};
    boost::fusion::for_each(tuple, a);
}
```

Note that the `operator()` of `struct A` modifies `x` in `struct A`. 
gcc 4.7.2 warns that ...\include\boost\fusion\algorithm\iteration\detail\for_each.hpp:77: error: passing 'const A' as 'this' argument of 'void A::operator()(const T&) [with T = int]' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I have not used boost::fusion, but from error message and [example from docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/algorithm/iteration/functions/for_each.html), it seems that `for_each` expects const object. I.e. `operator()` should be const as well. However you will be unable to mutate object.

Try this:

```
void operator()(const T& t) const {
    cout << t << endl;
}
```

**Edit:**

I've checked the sources (v. 1.53) and the declaration is `for_each(Sequence& seq, F const& f)`. So there is really no way to modify object itself. The only options I see are

either use static variables: `static int x;`

or use pointers:

```
struct A {
    template <class T>
    void operator()(const T& t) const {
        (*x)++;
        std::cout << t << std::endl;
    }

    int* x;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.x = new int;
    *(a.x) = 0;
    //...
```

In this case be careful with coping `A` instances, as pointers will all point to the same location.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, The question is all about iterating tuple and apply a function object which can be modified. And from your answer, I guess I cannot use boost::fusion with this purpose. Am I right?

Answer (score 3):

An easier, better way to do this is to use fusion::fold:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/fusion/algorithm/iteration/fold.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/fold.hpp>

namespace detail {
  struct A {
    typedef int result_type;
    template<typename T1, typename T2>
    int operator()( const T1& t1, const T2& t2 ) const {
      std::cout << t1 << "," << t2 << std::endl;
      return t1 + 1;
    }
  };
}

int main() {
  boost::fusion::vector<int, int, int> tuple{3,4,5};
  boost::fusion::fold(tuple, 0, detail::A());
}
```

Short of any syntax errors, this should produce:

0,3
1,4
2,5

Answer (score 1):

The solution is presented in the boost::phoenix::lambda documentation.

The secret is to do the various calculations in a lambda function outside of your functor.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/fusion/algorithm/iteration/for_each.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/for_each.hpp>

#include <boost/phoenix/core.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix/operator.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix/operator/arithmetic.hpp> 
#include <boost/phoenix/scope/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix/scope/local_variable.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix/function.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix/fusion.hpp>

namespace detail {
  struct A_impl {
    template<typename T1, typename T2>
    void operator()( const T1& t1, const T2& t2 ) const {
      std::cout << t2 << "," << t1 << std::endl;
    }
  };
  boost::phoenix::function<A_impl> const A = A_impl();
}

int main() {
  namespace phx = boost::phoenix;
  using boost::phoenix::arg_names::arg1;
  using boost::phoenix::local_names::_a;
  boost::fusion::vector<int, int, int> tuple{3,4,5};
  boost::fusion::for_each(tuple, phx::lambda( _a = 0 )[detail::A(arg1,_a++)]);
}
```

Short of any syntax errors, this should produce:

0,3
1,4
2,5